# Twig template list last modified files

Tags: html, twig

I am trying to get back the last modified files. I have mainly 2 types of folder structures on my site.

Basically I have this working for :-

```
Wallpapers
  -Wallpaper 1
  -Wallpaper 2
  -ETC
```

So the above is working. I then have a folder structure as below.

```
Discography
  -A
    -Ary
          Album 1
          Album 2
    -Aman
          Album 1
          Album 2
  -B
    -B21
          Album 1
          Album 2
    -Babbu
          Album 1
          Album 2
```

URL: /discography/a/ary/album-1/

So what I am looking to do is get back the last modified Album (Only)… 
All folders follow this same structure and all folders have an album inside of it.

Twig is as below:-

```
<div class="def-block widget">
                    <h4> Latest Discography Albums </h4><span class="liner"></span>
                    <div class="widget-content row-fluid">
                        <div class="videos clearfix flexslider">
                            <ul class="slides">
                                {% for p in page.find('/discography').children.order('date', 'desc').slice(0, 8) %}
                                <li class="featured-video">
                                    <a href="{{ p.url }}">
                                        {{ pages.find('/images/discography-artists/250x250').media.images[p.header.image~'.jpg'] }}
                                        <h3>{{ p.header.title }}</h3>
                                        <span>{{ p.header.album }}</span>
                                    </a>
                                </li><!-- slide -->
                                {% endfor %}
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div><!-- widget content -->
                </div><!-- def block widget videos -->
```

I cant seem to figure out the .children bit as unsure how to force it to look down 2 levels of folders for changes… Currently it goes down to the A/B/C folders and just outputs the last modified dates of these but I need it to go down to artist name (don't look for changes here) and then album-name (look for changes here) and list the last modified albums.

Comment: What is `{{ page }}`?

Comment: Variable on the page that is found.